# Compilation error caused by super wildcard

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, wildcard, super

I have the question about the code below.

Could you please tell me why exactly does compiler refuse to accept ty.add(new A());? After all A is a superclass of B (i. e., that corresponds to the requirements).

Error message is the following:

```
C.java:15: error: no suitable method found for add(A)
                ty.add(new A());
                  ^
    method List.add(int,CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual argument A cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: B from capture of ? super B
1 error
```

And here is the code (C.java):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class A
    {
    }
class B extends A
    {
    }
class C extends B
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        List<? super B> ty = new ArrayList<A>();
        ty.add(new A());
        ty.add(new B());
        ty.add(new C());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you just want to add subclass objects, then just declare your list as:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
list.add(new A());  // fine
list.add(new B());  // fine
```

---

The problem with your original list declaration is, compiler doesn't know what actual `ArrayList` type is being referred to by `List<? super B>`. For example, consider what all types of list are *capture-convertible* by `List<? super B>`:

- `List<A>` => `A` is super class of `B`
- `List<B>` => `? super B` can capture `B`
- `List<Object>` => `Object` is super class of `B`

So, adding a `new A()` might be valid in 1st and 3rd list, but it's not valid for `List<B>`. That is why compiler doesn't allow you to add `new A()`. However, declaring the list as `List<? super A>` would work fine. But, again just go with`List<A>`, that is what you want here.

The whole point of creating a list like - `List<? extends X>` or `List<? super X>` is to allow you to bind different concrete parameterized instantiation of `List<E>` to a single reference.

---

**References:**

- [Angelika Langer's - Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [When would I use a wildcard parameterized type with a lower bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ204)
- [JLS §5.1.10 - Capture Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what `? super B` means.  It means it's a class, unknown at compile time, that is `B` or a superclass of `B`.  The compiler only knows that `B` objects could be added, after all, it could be an `ArrayList<B>`.  So it must disallow adding an `A`.

To allow adding an `A`, consider `List<? super A>` or `List<A>` for the type of `ty`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I  really misinterpreted super in this case.

Answer (score 1):

? in this case is an existential quantifier, not a universal one.  `List< ? super B >` should be read as `for some unknown T such that B <: T, List< T >`.  Which means you can only add `B` instances or, paradoxically, any subclass of `B`, like `C` instances.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, paradoxically is the very suitable word.